# What is an Initial Stake-pool Offering (ISO)?

Tags: stake-pool, staking

The decentralized exchange Sundaeswap is planning an initial stake pool offering (ISO) on Cardano.
How does it work and what are the differences/advantages over an ICO?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a blog post that describes it quite well: https://sundaeswap-finance.medium.com/sundaeswaps-upcoming-initial-stake-pool-offering-iso-48fade1900a

Basically they will create a Cardano stake pool and you can delegate your ADA to this pool from your Yoroi or Daedalus wallet. The pool will take 50% - 100% margin fee (to fund the SundaeSwap developers). This means you will get less ADA as rewards from the pool. To compensate for this, they will send you some of their new SundaeSwap tokens.

---

EDIT: There is a more in depth blog post [here](https://www.sundaeswap.finance/posts/iso-update-1).

---

EDIT 2: On 11-JUL-2021 there was an update from the SundaeSwap team.
You can read it here: https://www.sundaeswap.finance/posts/iso-update-3

They changed it to a 0% margin fee model that only lasts for 5 epochs. It will be launched together with the DEX shortly after the Alonzo launch on mainnet.

Comment: "...the ISO funding model is distinct, and does not represent the sale of a security." do they have a layer backing up this claim? I see that people will do this because they think that their tokens will be more valuable in the future and that will be treated as security. Or am I missing something?
--- edit
Or the "trick" is that one is paying in the future rewards and not "money" that one has "at the moment". Sill would be nice to see some layer opinion about it :)

Comment: Looks like they are planing to show this legal framework: https://www.sundaeswap.finance/posts/iso-update-3